# jQuery divs "look up" to the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replicate this effect with jQuery - http://www.louisvuitton.fr/front/#/fra_FR/Homepage that moving "cards" which are following mouse like they are looking up to it.

I found one script which does mostly what I need but I need to add card movement on x/y and also would be great if each card had its own center point, not center of the screen. So when I am at one card, that card will be flat and other will look up to the mouse.

HTML:

```
<div id="collections">
        <article>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#collections {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}
    div#collections article {
        width: 20%;
        height: 15%;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: center center; 
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: rotateX( 0deg );
        transition: transform 50ms ease;
    }
        div#collections article:nth-child(1) {
            left: 20%;
            top: 30%;
            background: blue;
        }
        div#collections article:nth-child(2) {
            left: 40%;
            top: 10%;
            background: black;
        }
        div#collections article:nth-child(3) {
            right: 10%;
            top: 20%;
            background: pink;
        }
        div#collections article:nth-child(4) {
            left: 10%;
            bottom: 20%;
            background: purple;
        }
        div#collections article:nth-child(5) {
            right: 30%;
            bottom: 30%;
            background: green;
        }

    .notransition,
    .notransition div#collections,
    .notransition div#collections article {
        transition-duration: 0 !important;
        transition-delay: 0 !important;
    }

    .transition-reset,
    .transition-reset div#collections,
    .transition-reset div#collections article {
        transition-duration: 600ms !important; 
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.mcollections = function() {
    var doc = $(document),
      body = $("section#home"),
      docWidth = doc.width(),
      docHeight = doc.height(),
      horiz = 0,
      vert = 0,
      x,
      y,
      range = 30
      objekt = this;

    console.log("docWidth: "+docWidth);
    console.log("docHeight: "+docHeight);
    console.log("range: "+range);

    function noTransition() {
      body.removeClass("transition-reset"); //addClass("notransition");
    }

    function followMouse() {
      horiz = ((range*2)*(x / docWidth))-range;
      vert = -(((range*2)*(y / docHeight))-range);
      objekt.css({"transform" : "rotateX(" + vert + "deg) rotateY(" +horiz + "deg)"});
      noTransition();
    }

    function reset() {
      body.removeClass("notransition").addClass("transition-reset");
      objekt.css("transform", "");  
    }


    doc.mousemove(function(e){
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
    });

    doc.mousemove($.throttle(50,followMouse));

    doc.on({
      mouseleave : function(){ reset(); },
      mousedown : function(){ reset(); }
    });
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw259/

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little weird when each card acts as his own center but..

## Fiddle

You know, a little bit of Google'ing before asking a question here might help....


### Link

Anyways...

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('article').each(function(i,elem) {

        var xpos = $(elem).position().left;
        var ypos = $(elem).position().top;

        var cx = Math.ceil($(elem).parent().width() / 2.0);
        var cy = Math.ceil($(elem).parent().height() / 2.0);
        var dx = e.pageX - cx;
        var dy = e.pageY - cy;

        if (cardIsCenter) {
            cx = xpos + Math.ceil($(elem).width() / 2.0);
            cy = ypos + Math.ceil($(elem).height() / 2.0);
        }

        var tiltx = (dy / cy);
        var tilty = - (dx / cx);
        var radius = Math.sqrt(tiltx*tiltx + tilty*tilty);
        var degree = (radius * 20);

        $(elem).css('transform',
                    'rotate3d(' + tiltx + ',' + tilty + 
                    ',0,' + degree + 'deg)');

    });
});
```

Comment: Tahnk you for reply, but it seems like it is not working correctly - it has same functionallity as original script. Cards are not moving left/right/top/down and also each card does not have center in itself(example: wheh I have mouse over black, it is rotated signtly to top. It has to be flat, because I am with mouse on it and other cards has to look to it, also because mouse pointer is there).

Comment: I made one modification to script you posted as link which might help, just modified css to: `$(elem).css({
             '-webkit-transform' :'rotate3d(' + tiltx + ', ' + tilty + ', 0, ' + degree + 'deg)',
             'margin-left' : (e.pageX/100)*2 + 'px',
             'margin-top' : (e.pageY/100)*2 + 'px',
            });` which added movement to elements.. But still I need to figure out how to center each card

Comment: It is centered, I'm not sure why you're not noticing it

Comment: See this example - https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpgqhwhr5v6to31/Screenshot%202014-04-15%2018.08.29.png (screenshot from fiddle you posted) When I have cursor on purple card, it should be flat, but it is transformed. In this situation all cards except purple should have transformation. When I have mouse over black, all except black should be transformed, and so on for every card.

Comment: Oops, you're right, my apologies. I wanted to add an option to disable/enable whether the card is the center, so I had an `if` statement which set the `cx` and `cy` values to another value if so, but I forgot to move `dx` and `dy` which are initialized with `cx` and `cy` after the `if`. It's fixed now ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw259/2/)), and I've also added writing on each card its rotation.